# Unable to clear lock on ERRORLOG file in SQL Server to cycle error log

Tags: sql-server-2008, process, locking

Currently I'm having an issue with cycling the error log on two SQL Server Instances because the file is being used by another process. Simple I know but, when you try to kill the SPID it becomes hung and we are forced to restart the instance, which I want to avoid at all costs. To give you some background we use sqldm for our monitoring of the databases and received a message that our Error log reached its max size threshold and to cycle the error log. When I executed

```
exec sp_cycle_errorlog
```

I'm told the following message:

> Msg 17049, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_cycle_errorlog, Line 9
>   Unable to cycle error log file from 'J:\MSSQL10.SQL6\MSSQL\Log\ERRORLOG.1' to 'J:\MSSQL10.SQL6\MSSQL\Log\ERRORLOG.2' due to OS error '32(The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.)'. A process outside of SQL Server may be preventing SQL Server from reading the files. As a result, errorlog entries may be lost and it may not be possible to view some SQL Server errorlogs. Make sure no other processes have locked the file with write-only access.
>
> DBCC execution completed. If DBCC printed error messages, contact your system administrator.

Then I ran the following query in instance A and found that sqldm had a active process.

```
SELECT *
FROM sys.dm_exec_requests a
OUTER APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(a.sql_handle) b
WHERE session_id > 50
and session_id <> @@spid AND( text = 'xp_readerrorlog'  OR  text = 'sp_cycle_errorlog')
ORDER BY start_time a
```

Like I said before when I kill the SPID it became hung and remains in a rollback state (the process is not rolling back). My co-worker had this issue before on this same instance and contacted Idera for support, here was their response "The development team provided an update regarding this case. After reviewing the code, SQLdm only reads the SQL logs information in each collection and does not lock this resource. Given the behavior that you described,  this could be a problem of SQL Server 2008"

I believe they're right because we're only seeing this in these two instances. All other instances using sqldm are not reporting this problem which leads me to believe it is MS SQL Server causing it. This is where I'm stuck and that is trying to find out why there is a lock on this file and for what reason. I used Process explorer yesterday to search for any processes that are using ERRORLOG through the Find DLL and Handle window and there were mulitple processes touching this file. When I looked today I'm seeing now locks for this file and I still cannot cycle the error log. I ran the slect query above I'm still seeing sqldm SPID in both instances. I'm curious to see if anyone else has had this issue before whether they used sqldm or not. Any information will be helpful in tracking this issue down.

Thank you in advance.